# The convergence of $\int_{[-\pi, \pi]^d} \frac{1-(\frac{1}{d} \sum_{k=1}^d \cos \theta_k)^n}{1-\frac{1}{d} \sum_{k=1}^d \cos \theta_k}d \theta$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

This is a part of my homework whose deadline has passed. I couldn't solve it completely, so I want to know how to solve it.

I am struggling in evaluating the following integral:

$$ I_{d,n} = \int_{[-\pi, \pi]^d} \frac{1-f(\theta)^n}{1-f(\theta)}d \theta $$

where $\theta = ^t(\theta_1, ..., \theta_d) \in \mathbb{R}^d, f(\theta) = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{k=1}^d \cos \theta_k$.

I have to discuss the convergence of $\lim_{n \to \infty} I_{d,n}$ for each $d = 1, 2, ...$.

I guess it converges iff $d=1,2$, but I could only prove the convergence when $d=1$ using $\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2m} \theta = \frac{(2m-1)!!}{2m!!} \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You know that $f\le 1$

Comment: Hi, stupid question (maybe) why $d$ is over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]^{d}$ ?

Comment: @HenryLee Sorry, I'm not sure about your comment... if $f \leq 1$ then what theorem can I apply?

Comment: @SNR $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ so this is an integral over $[-\pi, \pi] \subset \mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion:

Let $I=[-\pi,\pi]$. Then

$$\int_{I^d}\frac{1-f^n(\theta)}{1-f(\theta)}\,d\theta=\sum^{n-1}_{k=1}\int_{I^d}f^{k}(\theta)\,\theta
$$

Each integral $\int_{I^d}f^{k}(\theta)\,d\theta\leq\frac{1}{d}\sum^d_{j=1}\int_{I^d}\cos^k(\theta_j)\,d\theta$ by Jensen's inequality.

The integrals $\int_{I^d}\cos^k(\theta_j)\,d\theta=(2\pi)^{d-1}W_k$ where $W_k$ are the [Wallis's integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) that you quoted in your problem). To analyze all that, you may require to use [Stirling's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) approximations formulas. The goal is to see if at the end you get a dominating convergent series.